# Difference between Heap Spraying, Heap Grooming and Heap Shaping

Tags: heap-memory, buffer-overflow

I fairly understand how a buffer overflow vulnerability is exploited and in my quest for further information I came across this [article](https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/39527.pdf) which I believe involves bypassing certain security features put in place to prevent exploitation.

I came across the following terms in the article

1. Heap Spraying *( I think is pushing the shell code on to the heap )*
2. Heap Grooming
3. Heap Shaping

I would like to better understand the definitions of the aforementioned terms. My understanding of the heap is rudimentary.

Comment: have you googled for all these terms, i can even see wiki pages for the same.

Comment: I haven't found any material on heap grooming and heap shaping. I understand what heap spraying is but I want to know the difference.